# Why is my unit test failing but code works on manual test - state does not appear to be changing in test through pumpAndSettle

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I am currently writing my first Flutter application and adding the first ever unit tests. This is also my first question on StackOverflow so please let me know if I have not provided sufficient info (or too much info!).

My home screen is made up of two main widgets which I have split out into two different classes. I would like to write a number of tests for the HomeScreen starting with the top first main widget which contains two buttons for you to scroll through the months. I have tested this manually on a physical android, an iphone and also on the simulators - the months are scrolling and working as I expect.

[MonthController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7iVA.png)

This is the home screen with the two main classes:

```
//home_screen.dart

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  DateTime _maxDate = DateTime.now();
  int _month = DateTime.now().month;
  int _year = DateTime.now().year;

  void setMMYY(int mm, int yy) {
    setState(() {
      _month = mm;
      _year = yy;
    });
  }

  void getMaxDate() {
    //set the max date
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getMaxDate();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(constants.APP_NAME),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: MonthController(setMMYY, _month, _year, _maxDate)),
          Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: MyData(_month, _year),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the MonthController class that would increment/decrement the month accordingly and display it in the centre text widget:

```
//month_controller2.dart

class MonthController2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int, int) setMMYY;
  int month;
  int year;
  DateTime maxDate;

  MonthController2(this.setMMYY, this.month, this.year, this.maxDate,
      {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  void _nextMonth() {
    if (month == 12) {
      month = 1;
      year += 1;
    } else {
      month += 1;
    }
    setMMYY(month, year);
  }

  void _prevMonth() {
    if (month == 1) {
      month = 12;
      year -= 1;
    } else {
      month -= 1;
    }
    setMMYY(month, year);
  }

  bool _isPastMaxDate() {
    DateTime thisMonth = DateTime(year, month, 1);
    DateTime nextMonth = DateTime(year, thisMonth.month + 1, 1);
    if (nextMonth.isAfter(maxDate)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  bool _isBeforeToday() {
    DateTime thisMonth = DateTime(year, month, 1);
    DateTime prevMonthTemp = thisMonth.subtract(
      const Duration(days: 2),
    );
    DateTime prevMonth = DateTime(prevMonthTemp.year, prevMonthTemp.month, 1);
    DateTime todayMonth =
        DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1);
    if (prevMonth.isBefore(todayMonth)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _isBeforeToday() ? null : _prevMonth,
          child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left_rounded),
          key: const Key("DECREMENT_MONTH"),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Text(
              DateFormat.yMMMM().format(DateTime(year, month)),
              style: _theme.textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _isPastMaxDate() ? null : _nextMonth,
          child: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_rounded),
          key: const Key("INCREMENT_MONTH"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the test that I have written to test that the months are increasing as expected when you tap on the increment month ElevatedButton. However, the test fails. When I adjust the test to test for thisMonth.year, thisMonth.month, it passes. This suggests to me that tester.tap has not changed the text or there is no "rebuild" happening. Why is that? I have tried to add longer durations to tester.pump / tester.pumpAndSettle but it does not appear to be working.

```
//home_screen_test.dart

void main() {
  var thisMonth = DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1);
  var nextMonthTemp = thisMonth.add(const Duration(days: 35));
  var nextMonth = DateTime(nextMonthTemp.year, nextMonthTemp.month, 1);
  var prevMonthTemp = thisMonth.subtract(const Duration(days: 2));
  var prevMonth = DateTime(prevMonthTemp.year, prevMonthTemp.month, 1);
  var maxDate = thisMonth.add(const Duration(days: 100));

  Widget createWidgetForTesting({required Widget child}) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: child,
    );
  }

  testWidgets('MonthController should increment month',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      createWidgetForTesting(
        child: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key("INCREMENT_MONTH")));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(
        find.text(
          DateFormat.yMMMM().format(
            DateTime(nextMonth.year, nextMonth.month),
          ),
        ),
        findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Error message:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "November 2021" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///....../test/home_screen_test.dart:47:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
<asynchronous suspension>
(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
  file:///....../test/home_screen_test.dart line 47
The test description was:
  MonthController should increment month
```

Separately, I have tried to write the test for month_controller_test.dart instead. To make the test work, I had to change the month_controller.dart to a stateful widget. While this is probably ok, I would still like to understand why the above did not work.